# How to fix error 'Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.dll' because it is being used by another process. When running u-sql locally in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure-data-lake, u-sql

When attempting to execute u-sql code locally in VS I get this error.  Using process explorer it says that Visual Studio (devenv.exe) is the process holding the handle.  I have tried cleaning, restarting VS and windows and many other things but get this 100% of the time when attempting to run locally.  Running against the cloud works fine.

```
Unexpected Exception 'System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'D:\src\GitHub\***\WebApp\****.Pipeline.USql\bin\Debug\ParseHourlyCSVToTable\Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.dll' because it is being used by another process.
```

Full output:

```
------ Rebuild All started: Project: ****.Pipeline.Usql, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
    Clean U-SQL Application Temporary Folder.
    Building Script: ParseHourlyCSVToTable.usql
D:\src\GitHub\****\WebApp\****.Pipeline.USql\ParseHourlyCSVToTable.usql(1,0): error External0: Unexpected Exception 'System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'D:\src\GitHub\****\WebApp\****.Pipeline.USql\bin\Debug\ParseHourlyCSVToTable\Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.dll' because it is being used by another process.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
   at ScopeCompiler.Parser.CopyFileIfDifferent(String sourceDirPath, String sourceFileName, String destDirPath, String destFileName)
   at Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.LocalParseSandboxer.CloneLocalRuntimeFiles(Configuration config, Settings settings)
   at Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.LocalParseSandboxer.PrivateParse(String script, Settings settings)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.LocalParseSandboxer.PrivateParse(String script, Settings settings)
   at Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.LocalParseSandboxer.CompileInSeparateAppDomain(String[] scripts, Settings settings, Configuration configuration)
   at ScopeCompiler.Parser.FullParse(String[] scripts, String filePath, CompilerEnvironment environment, Settings settings, Func`4 funcParse, String nebulaCommandLine)
   at Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.LocalParseSandboxer.FullParseInSeparateAppDomain(String script, String filePath, Settings settings, Configuration configuration)
   at Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.LocalCompiler.Compile(String script, String filePath, Boolean shallow, CommonCompileResult& result)
   at Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.LocalRunCompileService.Compile(CompileParameter parm)'
Done building project "***.Pipeline.Usql.usqlproj" -- FAILED.

========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Edit 1/26 adding procmon trace:

```
7:45:34.6944917 AM  LocalRunHelper.exe  3036    CreateFileMapping   D:\src\GitHub\****\WebApp\****.Pipeline.USql\bin\Debug\ParseHourlyCSVToTable\Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.dll   SUCCESS SyncType: SyncTypeOther
7:45:34.6945669 AM  LocalRunHelper.exe  3036    CreateFileMapping   D:\src\GitHub\****\WebApp\****.Pipeline.USql\bin\Debug\ParseHourlyCSVToTable\Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.dll   FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS   SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: PAGE_EXECUTE_READ|PAGE_NOCACHE
7:45:34.6945884 AM  LocalRunHelper.exe  3036    QueryStandardInformationFile    D:\src\GitHub\****\WebApp\****.Pipeline.USql\bin\Debug\ParseHourlyCSVToTable\Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.dll   SUCCESS AllocationSize: 1,048,576, EndOfFile: 112,088, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False
7:45:34.6947109 AM  LocalRunHelper.exe  3036    CreateFileMapping   D:\src\GitHub\****\WebApp\****.Pipeline.USql\bin\Debug\ParseHourlyCSVToTable\Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.dll   SUCCESS SyncType: SyncTypeOther
7:45:34.6947919 AM  LocalRunHelper.exe  3036    CloseFile   D:\src\GitHub\****\WebApp\****.Pipeline.USql\bin\Debug\ParseHourlyCSVToTable\Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.dll   SUCCESS 
7:45:48.2407503 AM  LocalRunHelper.exe  3036    CreateFile  D:\src\GitHub\****\WebApp\****.Pipeline.USql\bin\Debug\ParseHourlyCSVToTable\Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.dll   SUCCESS Desired Access: Write Attributes, Synchronize, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
7:45:48.2407875 AM  LocalRunHelper.exe  3036    SetBasicInformationFile D:\src\GitHub\****\WebApp\****.Pipeline.USql\bin\Debug\ParseHourlyCSVToTable\Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.dll   SUCCESS CreationTime: 0, LastAccessTime: 0, LastWriteTime: 0, ChangeTime: 0, FileAttributes: N
7:45:48.2408299 AM  LocalRunHelper.exe  3036    CloseFile   D:\src\GitHub\****\WebApp\****.Pipeline.USql\bin\Debug\ParseHourlyCSVToTable\Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.dll   SUCCESS 
7:45:48.2409359 AM  LocalRunHelper.exe  3036    CreateFile  D:\src\GitHub\****\WebApp\****.Pipeline.USql\bin\Debug\ParseHourlyCSVToTable\Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.dll   SUCCESS Desired Access: Read Attributes, Delete, Disposition: Open, Options: Non-Directory File, Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
7:45:48.2409958 AM  LocalRunHelper.exe  3036    QueryAttributeTagFile   D:\src\GitHub\****\WebApp\****.Pipeline.USql\bin\Debug\ParseHourlyCSVToTable\Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.dll   INVALID PARAMETER   
7:45:48.2410173 AM  LocalRunHelper.exe  3036    SetDispositionInformationFile   D:\src\GitHub\****\WebApp\****.Pipeline.USql\bin\Debug\ParseHourlyCSVToTable\Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.dll   CANNOT DELETE   Delete: True
7:45:48.2410430 AM  LocalRunHelper.exe  3036    CloseFile   D:\src\GitHub\****\WebApp\****.Pipeline.USql\bin\Debug\ParseHourlyCSVToTable\Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.dll   SUCCESS 
7:45:48.3611876 AM  LocalRunHelper.exe  3036    CreateFile  D:\src\GitHub\****\WebApp\****.Pipeline.USql\bin\Debug\ParseHourlyCSVToTable\Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.dll   SUCCESS Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
7:45:48.3612181 AM  LocalRunHelper.exe  3036    QueryNetworkOpenInformationFile D:\src\GitHub\****\WebApp\****.Pipeline.USql\bin\Debug\ParseHourlyCSVToTable\Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.dll   SUCCESS CreationTime: 1/26/2018 7:45:34 AM, LastAccessTime: 1/26/2018 7:45:34 AM, LastWriteTime: 1/11/2018 7:47:58 AM, ChangeTime: 1/1/1980 12:00:00 AM, AllocationSize: 1048576, EndOfFile: 112088, FileAttributes: N
7:45:48.3612365 AM  LocalRunHelper.exe  3036    CloseFile   D:\src\GitHub\****\WebApp\****.Pipeline.USql\bin\Debug\ParseHourlyCSVToTable\Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.dll   SUCCESS 
7:45:48.3616927 AM  LocalRunHelper.exe  3036    CreateFile  D:\src\GitHub\****\WebApp\****.Pipeline.USql\bin\Debug\ParseHourlyCSVToTable\Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.dll   SUCCESS Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
7:45:48.3617464 AM  LocalRunHelper.exe  3036    QueryNetworkOpenInformationFile D:\src\GitHub\****\WebApp\****.Pipeline.USql\bin\Debug\ParseHourlyCSVToTable\Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.dll   SUCCESS CreationTime: 1/26/2018 7:45:34 AM, LastAccessTime: 1/26/2018 7:45:34 AM, LastWriteTime: 1/11/2018 7:47:58 AM, ChangeTime: 1/1/1980 12:00:00 AM, AllocationSize: 1048576, EndOfFile: 112088, FileAttributes: N
7:45:48.3617645 AM  LocalRunHelper.exe  3036    CloseFile   D:\src\GitHub\****\WebApp\****.Pipeline.USql\bin\Debug\ParseHourlyCSVToTable\Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.dll   SUCCESS 
7:45:48.3618907 AM  LocalRunHelper.exe  3036    CreateFile  D:\src\GitHub\****\WebApp\****.Pipeline.USql\bin\Debug\ParseHourlyCSVToTable\Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.dll   SUCCESS Desired Access: Write Attributes, Synchronize, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
7:45:48.3619236 AM  LocalRunHelper.exe  3036    SetBasicInformationFile D:\src\GitHub\****\WebApp\****.Pipeline.USql\bin\Debug\ParseHourlyCSVToTable\Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.dll   SUCCESS CreationTime: 0, LastAccessTime: 0, LastWriteTime: 0, ChangeTime: 0, FileAttributes: N
7:45:48.3619495 AM  LocalRunHelper.exe  3036    CloseFile   D:\src\GitHub\****\WebApp\****.Pipeline.USql\bin\Debug\ParseHourlyCSVToTable\Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.dll   SUCCESS 
7:45:48.3623476 AM  LocalRunHelper.exe  3036    CreateFile  D:\src\GitHub\****\WebApp\****.Pipeline.USql\bin\Debug\ParseHourlyCSVToTable\Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.dll   SHARING VIOLATION   Desired Access: Generic Read/Write, Delete, Write DAC, Disposition: OverwriteIf, Options: Sequential Access, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: A, ShareMode: None, AllocationSize: 112,088
7:45:48.3624410 AM  LocalRunHelper.exe  3036    CreateFile  D:\src\GitHub\****\WebApp\****.Pipeline.USql\bin\Debug\ParseHourlyCSVToTable\Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.dll   SHARING VIOLATION   Desired Access: Generic Write, Read Data/List Directory, Read Attributes, Delete, Write DAC, Disposition: OverwriteIf, Options: Sequential Access, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: A, ShareMode: None, AllocationSize: 112,088
7:45:48.3625282 AM  LocalRunHelper.exe  3036    CreateFile  D:\src\GitHub\****\WebApp\****.Pipeline.USql\bin\Debug\ParseHourlyCSVToTable\Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.dll   SHARING VIOLATION   Desired Access: Generic Write, Read Attributes, Delete, Write DAC, Disposition: OverwriteIf, Options: Sequential Access, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: A, ShareMode: None, AllocationSize: 112,088
7:45:48.3626137 AM  LocalRunHelper.exe  3036    CreateFile  D:\src\GitHub\****\WebApp\****.Pipeline.USql\bin\Debug\ParseHourlyCSVToTable\Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.dll   SHARING VIOLATION   Desired Access: Generic Write, Read Data/List Directory, Read Attributes, Delete, Write DAC, Disposition: OverwriteIf, Options: Sequential Access, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: A, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: 112,088
7:45:48.3627039 AM  LocalRunHelper.exe  3036    CreateFile  D:\src\GitHub\****\WebApp\****.Pipeline.USql\bin\Debug\ParseHourlyCSVToTable\Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.dll   SHARING VIOLATION   Desired Access: Generic Write, Read Data/List Directory, Read Attributes, Delete, Write DAC, Disposition: OverwriteIf, Options: Sequential Access, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: A, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: 112,088
7:45:48.3627877 AM  LocalRunHelper.exe  3036    CreateFile  D:\src\GitHub\****\WebApp\****.Pipeline.USql\bin\Debug\ParseHourlyCSVToTable\Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.dll   SHARING VIOLATION   Desired Access: Generic Write, Read Attributes, Delete, Write DAC, Disposition: OverwriteIf, Options: Sequential Access, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: A, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: 112,088
7:45:48.3628705 AM  LocalRunHelper.exe  3036    CreateFile  D:\src\GitHub\****\WebApp\****.Pipeline.USql\bin\Debug\ParseHourlyCSVToTable\Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.dll   SHARING VIOLATION   Desired Access: Generic Write, Read Data/List Directory, Read Attributes, Write DAC, Disposition: OverwriteIf, Options: Sequential Access, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: A, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: 112,088
7:45:48.3629550 AM  LocalRunHelper.exe  3036    CreateFile  D:\src\GitHub\****\WebApp\****.Pipeline.USql\bin\Debug\ParseHourlyCSVToTable\Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.dll   SHARING VIOLATION   Desired Access: Generic Write, Read Data/List Directory, Read Attributes, Write DAC, Disposition: OverwriteIf, Options: Sequential Access, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: A, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: 112,088
7:45:48.3630398 AM  LocalRunHelper.exe  3036    CreateFile  D:\src\GitHub\****\WebApp\****.Pipeline.USql\bin\Debug\ParseHourlyCSVToTable\Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.dll   SHARING VIOLATION   Desired Access: Generic Write, Read Attributes, Write DAC, Disposition: OverwriteIf, Options: Sequential Access, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: A, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: 112,088
```

Comment: I am going to reach out to the tools team. in the meantime, are you sure you closed any command prompts from a previous local run?

Comment: I rebooted my machine, only launched VS and directly went to launch the local u-sql session via the in editor submit button.  So I'm sure that I don't have any other local runs active.   I get the same error.  I've edited the above question with the full output from the output pane in case that helps.

Comment: It looks like the file is in a locally cloned GitHub directory. Could it be that a GitHub related processed set the lock on the file and failed to clear it?

Comment: To my knowledge, except for the two cases I listed, our extension code has no other situations that would load that file from the project build outputs directory.   Regarding this issue, I wonder **if there are other 3rd party VS extensions that inspects assemblies from build outputs of other projects without your awareness**.

Comment: I just pulled a procmon trace (added above) which repros the issue.  Looks like it may be localrunhelper.exe keeping multiple handles open between CreateFileMapping and CreateFile and not closing them all in time before using the SetDispositionInformationFile to delete.

Comment: This is expected behavior. During script compilation, LocalrunHelper.exe shadow copies Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.dll from  ADLTools\2.3.2000.1\U-SQLSDK to D:\src\GitHub\****\WebApp\****.Pipeline.USql\bin\Debug\ParseHourlyCSVToTable\  and then load it in a new app domain to do the compilation. Also the failed deletion during that is expected too. Then, after compilation, localrunhelper.exe will restart and release all files. In your case, you mentioned that devenv.exe was also locking this file, which is unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

I could only think of the following situations that the Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.dll assembly in build target directory shall be locked by VisualStudio:

1. when in debug run mode where the lock shall be released when debug session ended.
2. Someone accidentally changed the value of Tools -> DataLake -> Options -> U-SQL Runtime SDK Directory to that build target folder.

Could you please check if the second situation is the case ?

Comment: Here is what the SDK directory is set to: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\ADL Tools\2.3.2000.1\U-SQLSDK

Comment: Added full output from the error to the question above.